# tensor_scatter_nd_update ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've always been able to use `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` without any problems to write into tensors, but I can't manage to figure our why it's not working with some specific tensors.

As a simple example, say I want to set certain values in `input=[[0 0 0]]` to `update=[[1 2 3]]`, based on a boolean mask `mask=[[1 0 1]]`.
I would simply do:

```
input=tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(input,tf.where(mask),update)
```

expecting the result of the operation to be `input=[[1 0 3]]`.

Instead I'm getting

```
ValueError: Dimensions [2,2) of input[shape=[1,3]] = [] must match dimensions [1,2) of updates[shape=[1,3]] = [3]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1 for ... with input shapes: [1,3], [?,2], [1,3].
```

I really can't work out what's wrong; I've always been able to use the function without issue even in much more complex cases.

Comment: Roughly speaking: Isn't this trying to stuff 3 values into 2 spots?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.

Part of the problem is indeed that `tf.where()` returns a 2-D tensor, but this came into play because I was using it to also generate the `updates` vector:

```
input=input=tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(input,tf.where(mask),tf.where(something_else))
```

The solution is to remove the extra dimension by:

```
input=input=tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(input,tf.where(mask),tf.squeeze(tf.where(something_else)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `something_else` ? If it is `update`, then it doesn't work

Comment: Use of `tf.squeeze` can not be an answer - it just transforms your toy example to 1D. It works only if the first dimension is 1.